# Ошибка в регулярке

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Пишу код:

```
$content[1] = '1<a href="http://www.site.com/11>11</a>2';
echo preg_replace('/<a href="http://www.site.com(.*?)</a>/', '', $content[1]);
```

Получаю вместо `$content[1] = '12';` ошибку:

> Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown
> modifier '/' in
> /home/gt/site/SUSTEM/PHP_Scripts/PARSER.php
> on line 50

Comment: @Юрий Зав, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

```
echo preg_replace('#<a href="http://www.site.com(.*?)</a>#', '', $content[1]);
```

У вас слеш используется и как дескриптор регулярки, и в самой регулярке. Замените его на другой дескриптор, например, на `#`.

Answer (score 1):

> У вас слеш используется и как дескриптор регулярки, и в самой регулярке. Замените его на другой дескриптор, например, на #.

Или используйте экранирование с помощью "\".

```
$content[1] = '1<a href="http://www.site.com/11>11</a>2';
echo preg_replace('/<a href="http:\/\/www.site.com(.*?)<\/a>/', '', $content[1]);
```